# change a autoloaded variable in codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter

I need to change a variable which is saved over the autoloader function.
Inside of a existing class (named "app") I can check if the variable is set.

```
 $this->options[$name];
```

Now I want to change the value of these autoloaded variable, inside my app.php class in this way

```
---
echo"old value: ".$this->options[$name].")";
$this->options[$name] = $value;                     
echo "new value:".$this->options[$name];
return true;    
...
```

for this, i get the correct new value.

The problem is, that it seems that this new value is not updated for the rest of the script!? If i access this variable later, i get the old value!?

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The only "variables" that persist across different pages/loads/refreshes .etc. are those that are stored in a session variable, cookie or database.**

To reiterate; this:

```
echo"old value: ".$this->options[$name].")";
$this->options[$name] = $value;                     
echo "new value:".$this->options[$name];
return true;
```

only affects the current instance at run-time (you can look at this as a page view). It will not persist. Same goes for config value changes in CodeIgniter.

Your only method is using some sort of file/database based storage.